# grep string containing `":"` patterns

Tags: bash, grep

This is the piece of my log file in server

```
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100","order_final_due_amount":"0.0000","items":[{"product_id"
```

I need to grep the logs which contain `"order_final_due_amount":"0.0000"` in my whole log file.

for this, I did like this

```
tail -f pp_create_shipment2018-12-05.log | grep "order_final_due_amount":"0.0000"
```

but I got zero results. what would be wrong on my tail command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"` is interpreted by the shell (it's used to quote e.g. spaces).

```
grep "order_final_due_amount":"0.0000"
```

is equivalent to

```
grep order_final_due_amount:0.0000
```

To pass `"` to `grep`, you need to quote it:

```
grep '"order_final_due_amount":"0\.0000"'
```

(Also, `.` is special in regexes and should be escaped.)

Comment: A useful corollary is the recommendation to *always* put single quotes around regular expression arguments in the shell. There are obviously corner cases where you cannot; but this is a good practical rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, you need to just escape the "." alone. The qr// takes cares of remaining.
Check this out:

```
> cat product.log
order items
items1
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100","order_final_due_amount":"0.0000","items":[{"product_id"
item2
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100","order_final_due_amount":"000000","items":[{"product_id"
items3
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100",order_final_due_amount:"0.0000","items":[{"product_id"
items4
>  perl -ne ' $pat=qr/"order_final_due_amount":"0\.0000"/; print if /$pat/ ' product.log
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100","order_final_due_amount":"0.0000","items":[{"product_id"
>
```

Thanks to melpomene, the below also works

```
> perl -ne ' print if /"order_final_due_amount":"0\.0000"/ ' product.log
"order_items_subtotal":"60.5100","order_final_due_amount":"0.0000","items":[{"product_id"
>
```

Comment: That's substantially identical to my answer: Use single quotes around the whole thing (to make the shell use all characters including `"` literally) and escape `.` for the regex engine. And there's no need for `qr//` or a separate `$pat` variable (you only use it once).